# How to upgrade to HEAD version of MongoDB in OS X homebrew?

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I installed mongoDB via

```
brew install mongodb --devel
```

How would I go about upgrading the **HEAD** since I didn't use the `--HEAD` flag during installation?

Comment: Have you tried brew update ?

Comment: I assumed HEAD was like Chrome Canary, or the Github pushes and not on the same branch. Beg to differ?